# Best practices for upgrading a package

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, deprecation, trial, trialforce

I have already released my package. However, I need to update this package with some fixes. I also have trialforce enabled, and I have created the trial templates.

I would now like to update this package. What are the best practices for me to update the package?

I have the following questions:

1.Do I have to deprecate the old version of the package?
2.Do I have to create a new trial template every time I upgrade the package? I would rather avoid doing this since we plan to update the package every two weeks. This will increase the work drastically for us.
3.How can I ensure the customers will always get the new version of the package? I have seen that some customers get the  old version of the package and other customers get the new version of the package. This happens when I have two packages (two versions) in the packaging organization, that is, I'm have not deprecated the older version.

Answer (score 1):

The most important step is to Log a Case in the Partner Portal and request both **Push Major** and **Push Patch** upgrades.

- Go back to Setup | Create | Packages and select your package
- Go to the Versions tab and press the Push Upgrades button
- On the next page, press the Schedule Push Upgrade Select the version
  you want to upgrade to and the Date/Time you want to do it
- Selecting the target version will bring up a list of the Orgs you can
  upgrade - select the ones you want and then press the Schedule
  button.

Now, I have not tried this personally so I assume that any New Customer trying to install this app will be taken over to latest version after this. You can get more information here : https://na14.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf